# how to read in files without using a file path in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there's a way to read in files without having to specify a filepath. For example, i'm currently using

```
import os

os.chdir('C:/Users/User/NewFolder')
```

I'm currently using Pandas to read csvs and i'm having to specify a file path using

```
Import pandas as pd
oo = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/NewFolder/ExampleFile')
```

Basically I just want to write it as

```
Import pandas as pd
oo = pd.read_csv('ExampleFile')
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the filepath? `chdir()` will `cd` to your directory, then the script can execute `pd.read_csv('ExampleFile')` directly.

Comment: where do you want to look for the files?

Comment: Does it not work? Try `pd.read_csv('./ExampleFile')`.

Comment: I guess what I truly don't know is where to actually place the file. Is there a specific place I should be placing it?

Comment: @JaneAlice You can place it wherever you want, as long as your python script has the permissions to access the file, which it should in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python will look in the folder the file is in (the python file you're running). So, if you have `analysis.py` and `Example.csv` in the same folder, then yes, you can do what you're suggesting. If not, then Python can't read your mind - you need to tell it where to look!

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: Happy to help. Also note that you can use bash/*nix terminal notation as well, so for example if the csv is in the parent folder, you can call `read_csv` on `../Example.csv`, or if it's in an adjacent folder called `foo` you could use `../foo/Example.csv`.